# How do you set the gpg-agent passphrase ttl?

Tags: freebsd, gnupg, passphrase, gpg-agent

I'm having troubles trying to get gpg-agent to cache my passphrase for a long time.

I'm using FreeBSD, GnuPG 2.1.11

I've created a .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file with the following

```
default-cache-ttl 34560000
max-cache-ttl 34560000
```

It doesn't seem to affect how long the passphrases are cached for, They still expire, I'm not sure how long, but roughly 15 mins.

Is there something else I need to do?  The FreeBSD server isn't being reset or anything so I don't think the gpg-agent is resetting.

Comment: just to be sure; you've restarted the gpg-agent? also, the .gnup_h_/gpg-agent.conf is a typo here, but not actually on your machine, right?

Comment: correct, i've restarted the gpg-agent.  And yes, that was a typo.

Comment: ok, i'm out. i changed the timeouts too and it works fine, I was first thinking it might be the actual length of your timeout, but i see other examples using it, so... at a loss.

Comment: Reading this is a server -- have you configured `gpg-agent` for the right user account?

Comment: found it was the length of the timeout.  There might be a limit, but I couldn't find any doc on it.